# No se inicia el diseño de mi layout en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-layout, layout

Buenas quisiera saber por que no carga la parte grafica de mi layout, al principio funcionaba pero después de un tiempo dejo de jalar.
Versión Android Studio: 4.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, a que te refieres con "dejo de Jalar"?

Comment: De repente no carga la parte grafica